# Git cherry-pick is the right solution

Tags: git, github

I have a master branch which only gets deployed to production (A is currently deployed). Now we have a feature which is not fully developed (B,C) and has been committed to master. There is a prod issue which we need a fix and deployment(D). What is the best strategy to deploy the fix without affecting the current development?

We can revert to A then commit D and deploy in prod. Then cherry-pick B,C on top of D and continue development. Is my strategy going to work?

Or how to put D in between A and B?

A-B-C-D

Comment: Sounds like you need a branching strategy. One option is https://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/. But the simplest is probably to just never merge something that's not completed and ready to deploy.

Comment: Assuming you have a `prod` branch that points to `A` right now and a `main` (or `master` branch) that is pointing to D, if you would like to avoid B and C to be merged into `prod` currently, just cherry-pick D into `prod`.

Comment: I dont have any branch right now..everything gets deployed from master

Comment: @fredrik..I understand..but can this be salvaged by git commands

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Revert, then revert the reversions later.

You can revert your un-deployed commits to clear them from master. You can then commit your patch and deploy that. Then you can simply revert the revert commits to re-implement them, then deploy.